# Accessing a sibling (?) variable in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have a base class, which includes all other files. I can access this class (it is public) throughout my entire application (by way of `base::$var` or `base::function()`).

One of the functions of this base class is to load additional frameworks. One of the frameworks looks like the following (simplified) - based off a singleton that I saw here on SO.

```
<?php
class someOtherFramework{

    public static $site = array();

    public static function Instance() {
        static $inst = null;
        if ($inst == null) {
            $inst = new someOtherFramework();
        }
        return $inst;
    }

    private function __construct() {

    }
}

base::createInstance('blah', 'someOtherFramework');
?>
```

The call to `base::createInstance` is the following:

```
public static function createInstance($variable, $class){
    if (class_exists($class)){
        $variable = $class::Instance();
    }
}
```

The goal is that I can access `$blah` in the same way that I do `$base`. Is it possible? Does this make sense? If not, what's the best way to provide access to a class another developer might want to use?

Comment: I've read through the supplied answers and comments, and I'm still evaluating the best way to go - do I simple create those classes manually on demand, and make it a member of my given class? I'll finish up this answer today once I've gotten something I'm happy with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way of accessing your 'blah' variable, is if it was a global. which isn't really OOP design.

Maybe you should look into creating a Registry class which is passed around by reference that contains all of those variables? For myself, I find it neater to do that (and much less of a nightmare thank you Eclipse IDE!) - and personally, I don't like Singleton classes

... though, the code you posted, doesn't exactly make sense. Can you post more details?

Comment: The reason is that I have created a base framework which I use in my PHP projects. Since my framework (in my profile) is public, I'd like to be able to give other developers a means to drop in their own framework, and have it loaded + automatically available to all appropriate modules within their applications.

Comment: If your only creating singletons, would it really matter what the variable is called? Since they can just call $class::Instance(); or you can make every class of yours inherit a function called getInstance(), which determines what the class being accessed is named, and just calls the Instance(); of that class

Comment: I know this gets confused a lot, but OOP design has little bearing on the other language features; specifically variable scoping.

Comment: I ended up going with a chain of command style pattern: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/#N101DE as it allows me to register an object as a part of my framework and pass information to it.

Comment: @mario as long as you can pass them into a class context, I guiess its fine. But everytime I think of globals in php I am just reminded of `function bla() { global $ooyea; }` ... ****shudders****

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`$GLOBALS`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php), the array that holds all global variables. It's accessible from within a function. Maybe better, there's also the [`global`](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword and [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Using `$GLOBALS`, you'd do something like this:

```
$GLOBALS[$variable] = $class::Instance();
```

With the `global` keyword, your function would look like this:

```
global $$variable;
if (class_exists($class)){
    $$variable = $class::Instance();
}
```

Comment: While a good answer, I ended up going with a chain of command style interface. Check out Dimitri's answer.